# Use from specific language in a request validation - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel project is a multi language.
I use from Laravel validator in api. Now errors will appear with the language set in the application.
But I want all the errors in api section to be returned in English.
Use `\App::setLocale('en');` in the ApiContrpller, Exactly, not what I want!
How can I set an specific language only in the request validator?

Comment: If you want all the errors in api section to be returned in English then you should probably make a middleware which changes the application local and add it into the api middleware group in App\Http\Kernel

Comment: But I prefer don't change the app local, so there isn't anyway we choice a language in validation? :(

Comment: I don't think so. Unless you change it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the language in that request, you should create a middleware for your API that change the app locale:

```php
app()->setLocale('es');
```

Comment: I don't want change locale, validation is a part of locale section, I only need change the request validation language

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use different locale in FormRequest only, you could do something like this:

```
class OrderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected string $appLocale;

    protected function prepareForValidation(): void
    {
        $this->appLocale = app()->getLocale();

        app()->setLocale($this->input('locale', 'en'));
    }

    protected function passedValidation(): void
    {
        app()->setLocale($this->appLocale);
    }

    // your code...
}
```

NOTE: There is a `setLocale` and `setDefaultLocale` method on the `FormRequest` but it didn't work for me.